# Can 去 be used as a 介词(Preposition)?

Tags: preposition

I don't think 去 in the example below is necessary since 走 already implies, "go",
unless the 去 in used as a 介词(preposition).

```
去故宫(我)怎么走？ 
How should I go to 故宫？
```

I also do not think that that sentence is verb-serialized(去+走).

Should it be just something like this?

```
故宫我怎么去？
```

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that it's not verb serialization, but 去 is still a verb in this sentence. Instead, 怎么走 is the interrogative adverbial phrase that modifies the V+O 去故宫. Consider the sentence structure of a possible answer to the question:

```
我 骑车     去 故宫。
S  Adv.     V  O
```

The structure needs no explanation. Now replacing the adverbial phrase with an interrogative one, the sentence becomes an interrogative sentence:

```
我怎么走去故宫？
```

Invert the sentence for emphasis:

```
去 故宫 我 怎么走？
V  O   |S  Adv.
```

In the case of 故宫我怎么去, it's the inversion of 我怎么去故宫, where the interrogative adverbial phrase is simply 怎么 without a verb.

```
我 怎么 去 故宫？
S  Adv. V  O

故宫 我 怎么 去？
O   |S  Adv. V
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one quick question to make sure... is that so "故宫我怎么去?" is also grammatically okay to use then?

Comment: @YayCplusplus Yes it is grammatical and sounds very natural.

Comment: @YayCplusplus You are very welcome:)